# Data filter failing when reading from excel due to em-dashes / hypen in python using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to read the excel file and then print the results with a specific value in the column filter. But the result fails which have em-dashes/hyphens. If I chose any other column filter value it works. Please help to make this query work. Excel file is date is below to see the data and filter column 'category'. It looks like em-dash. once you open my excel you can exactly see.

Excel file test.xlsx contents filter is based on column 'Category'

| Name | Age | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | 15 | cata |
| Joseph | 21 | catb |
| Krish | 22 | cata |
| John | 32 | Cat – AB |

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
DATA_DIR = Path.cwd() / r'E:'
excelA = DATA_DIR / 'Test.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(excelA)

values1 = df1

# Seem em dash below code fails but replace catg = ['cata'] them code works
catg = ['Cat – AB']



df_new = df[df['Category'].isin(catg)]

print(df_new)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to replace the em-dash with dash which will make it easier to compare.

```
def func(word):
    return word.replace(chr(8211), chr(45))

df['Category'] = df['Category'].apply(func)
```

Here 8211 is the ASCII representation of em-dash and 45 for dash.

```
df[df['Category'] == 'Cat - AB']

   Name  Age  Category
3  John   32  Cat - AB
```

Comment: Thank you it really helped